# Absolute value of GRBVar

Tags: java, optimization, gurobi

I need to rewrite following equotation to Gurobi:
|x| = max{x, −x} = z

I tried it this way:

```
model.addConstr(z, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, x, "z");
model.addConstr(z, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, -x, "z"); // error operator - is undefined
```

however because of no operator overload in Java "-" is undefined for GRBVar. Any idea how to work around ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute value constraint [GRBModel.addGenConstrAbs()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/java_grbmodel_addgenconstr4.html) was added in version 7.0.  Change your code to:

```
model.addGenConstrAbs(z, x, "MyAbsValConstr");
```